# In Unity, error message : Failed to build apk

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins

I make a project and switch platform to android,
and change the bundle identifier.

I just test to build and run but it occurs to error message.
First,

```
**CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to build apk.**
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "E:\StudyProject\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -


stderr[
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/build/ApkCreationException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:128)
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

and Second,

```
**UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Build failed with errors.**


at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x001b9] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:162 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00050] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:83 
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

I install the Unity just before, and didn't setting.

I don't know why this problems occur.

If you know about it, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to choose latest version of JDK selection in Unity?

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1157530/unsupported-majorminor-version-520-android-build-e.html